# Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2010 with VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure-devops

We have an old MVC2 project stranded in Visual Studio 2010 and assigned to TFS 2010.
Is it possible to copy this project into VSTS and access VSTS in Visual Studio 2010?
Because it is an old project there is no need to migrate the version history.
What are my options?

Comment: Were you actually running into a problem we can help you solve setting this up?, I don't see any reason why you couldn't get this working, so long as you use the correct version of msbuild to build your project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) from Visual Studio 2010, however, you will need two software updates:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34677) (KB2736182)
- [TFS 2012 compatibility update for Visual Studio 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2662296/fix-an-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1-is-available-to-add-compatibi) (KB2662296)

Having said that, upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 *is* preferable if you can do that.

To bring your data into VSTS, the easiest way to do that is to use the [TFS to VSTS migration tool](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/), which providers an easy, high-fidelity migration into the cloud.  However, since you don't require history, you can also perform a [manual migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migrate-to-vsts-from-tfs), where you simply check your assets into TFS directly.